# Reading a string from a webpage

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch

I've looked into this a lot on stack overflow and have found some instances where it may work for what I want to do, but I'm not gonna lie, I'm a tad lost. I have a very simple string that shows up on a webpage that i want to read into the application, parse it, then display it inside some UITextFields. The URL is `mtgox.com/data/code/ticker.php`. It's a php page that yields a simple JSON string, a one liner, looking like the following:

```
{"ticker":{"high":14.6999,"low":14.04,"avg":14.379509781,"vol":10981,"last":14.44278,"buy":14.4302,"sell":14.44278}}
```

How can I read this string into my application and then parse it? I was thinking of possibly using the `UIWebView` class and the `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptString` method on the site, but I don't know much about javascript, nor do I know if that would work.

I've seen some people mentioning the use of a JSON library, but don't know if that's what will be the best for what I need, and if that will even work; and I feel that might be a tad overkill given I'm only parsing one line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you insist not to use JSON parser (library installation and other framework config hasle), the 
code below has been tested and work fine for your URL:

Place this code in the view controller that has the textfield.

```
- (NSDictionary *)parseJSONFromSomeURL
{
    NSURL *pageURL = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mtgox.com/code/data/ticker.php"];
    NSString *JSONString = [NSString stringWithContentsOfURL:pageURL encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

    JSONString = [JSONString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"{" withString:@""];
    JSONString = [JSONString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"}" withString:@""];
    JSONString = [JSONString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@""];

    NSArray *components = [JSONString componentsSeparatedByString:@","];

    NSMutableDictionary *result = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
    for (NSString *parts in components)
    {
        NSArray *subComponents = [parts componentsSeparatedByString:@":"];
        // First element has 3 items (it has ticker)
        if ([subComponents count] > 2)
        {
            [result setValue:@"" forKey:[subComponents objectAtIndex:0]];
            [result setValue:[subComponents objectAtIndex:2] forKey:[subComponents objectAtIndex:1]];
        }
        else
        {
            [result setValue:[subComponents objectAtIndex:1] forKey:[subComponents objectAtIndex:0]];
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```

Hopefully it help to solve your problem.

Comment: HA! Love it :) Thanks! I might end up using this code over the JSON library simply due to the fact that this is just a handful of code versus the multiple class files needed to include the JSON library framework. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I suggest going through [this tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/tutorial-json-over-http-on-the-iphone/), which should show you what you need to know to get the JSON-encoded information from the webpage and parse it.

Comment: Ok, I went through the tutorial and it does do exactly what I need in terms of parsing the page out and dropping the info into an NSDictionary. Now I'm getting a crash when I try to set the text of a textField using the value of the specific key in that dictionary.

Comment: `2011-07-09 22:55:45.093 BTC Exchange[1862:ef03] 14.6999
2011-07-09 22:55:45.094 BTC Exchange[1862:ef03] -[NSDecimalNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a7a670
2011-07-09 22:55:45.095 BTC Exchange[1862:ef03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSDecimalNumber length]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6a7a670'
*** First throw call stack:
terminate called throwing an exception`

Comment: Ok, it turns out I can call the NSNumber class's `stringValue` call to convert the NSDecimalValue extracted from the dictionary into a usable string! Silly me :P should pay attention to the API more.